# Inserting an image into SQL Server from another computer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I insert an image into SQL Server from a client computer?

```
INSERT INTO imagetable (imagecolumn)
   SELECT BulkColumn
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Image.png', Single_Blob) AS img
```

I'm getting this error and after searching I found out it's because the SQL Server is looking for the image path on the server machine. My `imagecolumn` is a `varbinary(MAX)` datatype.

> Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Image.png" could not be opened.
>   Operating system error code 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.)

Comment: Not ideal, but you could try sharing the file on the client and changing the path to the network path of the file. I imagine you would also need to give read permission to whatever account sql server uses.

Comment: Two possible issues here, 1) Make sure that file and Path exists. 2) The user has (read/write) permissions on this file.

Comment: @M.Ali: 3) The server sees drive C: as the local hard disk on the server and not the C: drive on the remote computer (which is clearly stated in the question itself).

Comment: You have two options: 1) Copy the file to the server's local drive and load it from there, or 2) Share the local computer's drive and then insert using that network location via a UNC path.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried sharing the folder where the file is located and i'm getting an access denied error when inserting, what do i need to do on the folder? i'm using a windows 7 machine

Comment: You need to give the SQL Server account permissions to read from the folder. You may have difficulty doing so, because you're doing the totally inappropriate thing of putting the files in the root of C: (which is only allowed for administrators, and if you've turned off  the default security settings). Put the file in a folder, share that fikder, and give read access to the SQL Server account. How to do that would be a question for [su], because it's about OS configuration and not programming. (The question probably already exists there in multiple forms; a search should turn it up.)